# Composer Autoload psr-4 issue

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

i'm a newbie at composer, so just bear with me,
So i have a package, which i'm loading from local folder, and while using it, i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'mypkg\Layer\EasyCPT' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testwp\app\Cpt\location.php on line 5

My Composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"vcs",
        "url":"C:/xampp/htdocs/mypkg"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "mypkg/particles": "master"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

Package's Composer:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Talha Abrar",
        "email": "talha@themegeek.io"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "Mypkg\\": "particles/"
    }
}
```

Psr 4:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Mypkg\\' => array($vendorDir . '/Mypkg/particles/particles'),
    'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/app'),
);
```

how i am using it:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Cpt;
use Mypkg\Layer\EasyCPT;

class Location extends EasyCPT{
    protected $plural = 'locations';
}
```

Main auto-loading file:

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Init\EasyWP;

    new EasyWP();
```

Comment: try ```composer dump-autoload``` inside your root project

Comment: I tried that many times, still did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the namespace as:

```
use Particles\Layer\EasyCPT;
```

but in `autoload` section defining as:

```
"Mypkg\\": "particles/"
```

which is not consistent.

You should replace `Mypkg` with the right namespace name, e.g.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "Particles\\": "particles/"
    }
}
```

So requesting `Particles\Layer\EasyCPT` namespace will look for class in `particles/Layer/EasyCPT.php` file.

As per [Composer's PSR-4 documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4):

> Under the `psr-4` key you define a mapping from namespaces to paths, relative to the package root. When autoloading a class like `Foo\\Bar\\Baz` a namespace prefix `Foo\\` pointing to a directory `src/` means that the autoloader will look for a file named `src/Bar/Baz.php` and include it if present. Note that as opposed to the older `PSR-0` style, the prefix (`Foo\\`) is not present in the file path.

If your project doesn't follow PSR-4 approach, use classmap instead to scan for all of your classes, e.g.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["particles/"],
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["/tests/"]
}
```

To regenerate `autoload` manually, run:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

and check autoload files in `vendor/composer/` whether the references to classes were generated correctly.